# Emberjs 1.0.0-RC3: Can't use send to call controller method from view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Normally, we can access a method declared in the controller from the views using: **this.get('controller').send('method');**. In this simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfXTb/1/), that is failing with: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined.

Here is the entire code in the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfXTb/1/)**.

```
 App = Ember.Application.create();

 App.YesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

   cow: function(){
       console.log('say mooooo') ;
    }  
 });

 App.YesView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'yes',
   um:  function(){    
     this.get('controller').send('cow');
   }
});
```

The entire view:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
  {{render yes}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='yes'>
   <h1> Can't use send to call controller method from view</h1>
    <button {{action 'um' target='view.content'}}> can't call controller from view</button>

  <button {{action 'cow'}}> controller action works</button>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `target=view` rather that `target=view.content`, otherwise you're trying to call send on the model, which is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it's possible to call the `cow()` method in your controller like this:

```
App.YesView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'yes',
  um: function() {
    this.get('controller').cow();
    //this.controller.cow() // <-- this should work also
  }
})
```

Comment: Heron thanks for the suggestion but either approach only works when using **target=view". So I upvoted your answer and accepted Martin's.